# PHP XPath text between two elements

Tags: php, xpath

This is my HTML

```
<dd><h1>Article Name 1</h1><p>
<div align="right"><a href="mailto:author1@email.com">Author 1</a></div>
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ... <br>(sometimes is <p>)
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ... <br>(sometimes is <p>)
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ... <p>
<div align="right"><a href="mailto:author2@email.com">Author 2</a></div>
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ...<p>
<hr noshade>

<dd><h1>Article Name 2</h1><p>
<div align="right"><a href="mailto:author1@email.com">Author 3</a></div>
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ... <p>
<div align="right"><a href="mailto:author2@email.com">Author 2</a></div>
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ... <br>(sometimes is <p>)
... HTML Text (includes HTML tags) ...<p>
<hr noshade>
```

I need to parse article name, authors and their texts. I managed to parse name and authors, but I still can't parse text of article for each author.

This is sample HTML is from 1998 and I'm trying parse it from internet archive on Wayback Machine so I don't have any control on actual code.

Comment: Does that HTML markup really start with `<dd><h1>Article Name</h1><p>`? Where is the closing `</p>` for that `<p>` at the end? While it is fine to shorten samples for a question to ask precisely and in a compact way in this case I wonder what the HTML input structure is and what tree the HTML parser builds before being able to ponder an XPath expression or two to select content. So perhaps spell out a bit more of the sample.

Comment: I've update my question. I'v used regular expression to get "my" HTML part from archive page and then I loaded to DOMDocument just this article parts. and yes - article starts with `<dd>` and ends with `<hr>`. There is no `</p>` closing tag. here is url of archive https://web.archive.org/web/20020305123037/http://edoctors.underground.sk/dna/offline.php?ezine=17